# What is the best way to implement active record in java?

Tags: java, activerecord

I wonder if with a simple `Map<String,Object>` implementation for plain records is enough.

I want to do it similar to Ror. When you add a field to the table in the database automatically you have access to the field in the Dto.

I don't want to add a field and then have to add the same field to the DTO declaration. It isn't DRY.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://javalite.io/ - this is an implementation of ActiveRecord in Java

Comment: I see what you did here ;)

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're looking for a is very lightweight Object Relational Mapping tool?

If you want to roll your own, then there is a tiny example one as part of [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ad-gwt2/) on developerWorks.

You may want to look at any number of others but Hibernate, JPA and JDO are probably the most popular. [Prevayler](http://www.prevayler.org) type systems may be what you're looking for. Of course, none of this may not be what you're after. Could you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want.

Java is a static language, so you cannot do the RoR ActiveRecord trick where it adds the methods to the class dynamically, unless you want to manipulate the byte code yourself.

This means that you have to declare a mapping somewhere between a java method (getter/setter) and the database table.

You can do code generation of java classes based upon tables, maybe this is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If **DRY** is the important keyword to you, then you should consider source code generation from your database schema (or vice-versa). In the ORM world, Hibernate ships with excellent source code generation facilities.

Since you are not looking for an ORM-solution, I can recommend my database abstraction tool jOOQ to you: http://jooq.sourceforge.net

It combines ActiveRecord-like structures generated from your database schema, as well as a querying-DSL to actually execute your queries in a typesafe manner.